# Replace ZeroMQ's select() on windows

Tags: zeromq

It is unbelievable that ZeroMQ uses select() on Windows, I didn't know that until I have completes my code and started performance test. They should present this information on their web site with big red font.

Is there anyway to replace ZeroMQ's select()?

IOCP is proactor model and can't be easily integrated into it, how about WSAEventSelect, this is also a reactor model and have a near performance like poll.

Another choice for me is http://nanomsg.org/,  but it is still alpha.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main objectives in Zeromq is to provide a consistent API for communication between threads, processes, nodes, and clusters. Protocol specific optimization is outside of this scope because of the ways that it can effect other areas of communication. For example, shared memory would be a better form of IPC, but UNIX domain sockets make a consistent API easier. It would also be nice to know when an endpoint disconnects, but how would you implement such behavior between threads?

Their main goal is to allow every pattern to work the same way regardless of topology, protocol, system, or language, to the point that any mixture can be used regardless of how odd it may seem (node.js  Websockets communicating with C# brokers passing messages to Ruby and PHP workers which share work with java threads, etc.)

Each of it's features would be enhanced greatly if optimised for each specific protocol and system, but that would also make uniform patterns close to impossible.

BTW, they might accept a pactch if you could find a way to implement iocp while still maintaining this versatility and neutrality.

PPS, nanomsg is made by one of the main original developers of Zeromq. Crossroads.IO is a direct fork of Zeromq, by original Zeromq developers as well and including some developers of nanomsg. if I'm not mistaken, Nano will likely become the core of crossroads when complete.